# Function parameter overwritten

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

The following node.js module logs `ModelA` two times and `ModelB` two times during initialization, as expected. Then the model parameter is somehow overwritten and when I attempt to use the routes, it always logs `ModelA`.

```
module.exports = (model) => {
  console.log(model.modelName);
  return (db) => {
    console.log(model.modelName);

    router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(model.modelName);
      model.insertMany(req.body, (err, docs) => {
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.json(docs);
      });
    });

    return router;
  };
};
```

The module is used like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const plural = require('./plural.js');

module.exports = (db) => {
  router.use('/a', plural(db.ModelA)(db));
  router.use('/b', plural(db.ModelB)(db));

  return router;
};
```

Comment: The code doesn't look correct. You should be returning a middleware or `Router` instance from your function with the `db` parameter because you're using the result of that function as the argument being passed to `router.use()`. Currently it's returning `undefined` by default.

Comment: I shorted the code a bit and `return router;` got lost. The real code is returning a router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only creating a new `Router` instance at the top of plural.js, then you need to instead create the `Router` instance inside the function that adds the route handler (`router.post(...)`), otherwise you're returning the same `Router` instance both times and the second call to `plural()` is just appending to the same `Router`. Because of that, the `ModelA`-based route handler will always execute first and respond to the request (unless it calls `next()`). For example:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
// const router = new Router();  // <--- move this line ...
module.exports = (model) => {
  return (db) => {
    const router = new Router(); // <--- ... to here

    router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
      console.log(model.modelName);
      model.insertMany(req.body, (err, docs) => {
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.json(docs);
      });
    });

    return router;
  };
};
```